# pygtk - questions about ListViews: update/appending values

Tags: listview, pygtk

i have some general questions about using `ListView`s and `ListStore`s etc..

My program contains a ToDo-list which is a list of `Task`-objects. A `Task`-object has two attributes: `title` and `progress`. Now i want to display these ToDo-list in a `ListView` showing the `title` of the task in the first column and the `progress` in the second column.

So i could create a `ListView` with two `TreeViewColumn`s, each with a `CellRendererText` and a data function (`set_cell_data_func`) to set the appropriate column-text (`title`- or `progress`-attribute of the `Task`-object).

Of course, the `progress` of a task can change over time in another thread. So the progress-cells should be updated to show the new value. But how can i tell the `ListView` that the `Task`-object has changed and the view should be updated?

And what is the simplest way to keep track of list-changes? For example a new `Task`-object is added to the ToDo-list. Do i need to append the new added `Task`-object to the `ListStore` by myself or is there an easier way? ... because i would have two lists: the original ToDo-list and the `ListStore` which seems to be unnecessary.

So what is the best/simplest/easiest way to show my ToDo-list in a `ListView`? :-)

Best regards,
Biggie

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use gtk.ListStore as your list model and primary\only "TODO list" data source , once you change values in the model, your list view content should be updated, smth like this:

```
# get first row of the list store
iter = self.model.get_iter_first()
# set new values to the first column
self.model.set_value(iter, 1, 'new value')
# set new values to columns 0 and 1
self.model.set(iter, 0, 'new 0', 1, 'new 1')
```

if you need to track changes for your model fields, connect to the "[row-changed](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodel.html#signal-gtktreemodel--row-changed)" signal:

```
self.model.connect("row-changed", self.on_model_changed, 0)
...   
def on_model_changed(self, treemodel, path, iter, user_param1):
    print 'model_changed ' + treemodel.get_value(iter, 0)
```

hope this helps, regards